# Android fragments preserve content

Tags: android, rest, android-fragments

I am using `ViewPager` `Activity` with 3 tabs. Each tab having a single `Fragment` to display(swipable). For each `Fragment`, the data is retreieved from server via rest api and displayed in form of cards(using [this library](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib)). Hence, I was coding like this:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    fetch_item1_card1(); //Fetches Data 1 and displays on card 1 
    fetch_item2_card2(); //Fetches Data 2 and displays on card 2 
    ...
}
```

This was working good until when I clicked a button that shows a card detail in new `Activity`(Lets say `Activity` B). So, on pressing back button, I was brought to the `Fragment` mentioned above(using `finish();`), and the same data is again retrieved from api.

Hence I thought to only fetch data when the `Activity` is first created. I achieved this by doing something like this:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    if(savedInstanceState == null) {
        fetch_item1_card1(); //Fetches Data 1 and displays on card 1 
        fetch_item2_card2(); //Fetches Data 2 and displays on card 2 
    }
    ...
}
```

But the problem now is, whenever I get back from `Acitivity` B (using `finish();`) ,the data is not there. I have to re-fetch it manually via api.

I want to fetch the data ones from the internet, display it until user re-fetch  it manually. How can I achieve this? I could have kept the code outside of `savedInstanceState` but that would mean a lot of queries via API each time user gets back from activity. Can it be minimized in some other way?

Comment: You should be caching your retrieved data, not accessing the internet every time the Fragment loads. Unless you expect the data to have changed every time that it loads. It seems like you are expecting the data to only be manually refreshed, so there is no reason you can't at least dump the returned data into a SharedPreference to load it from later.

Comment: @Downvoter: Care to explain downvote?

Comment: @Knossos What if the data goes on increasing with time. Think of it like a dashboard or facebook Wall. I am thinking caching a certain portion of dashboard is enough in that case.

Comment: If it only gets refreshed manually. Then always cache it. There is no downside. Overwrite the cache when you are polling manually from the server. You will have to decide whether too much is too much.

Answer (score 0):

in this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) you can find an explanation of your problem
in fact you must do this:

adding this method:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("curChoice", mCurCheckPosition);
}
```

Which you can use later like this:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            // Restore last state for checked position.
            mCurCheckPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("curChoice", 0);
        }
}
```

hope it works.

Comment: My problem requires a strategy for saving whole fragment data and not fetching it from api again and again. How does saving a list position helps me?

Comment: try to use the Volley library 
it developed by google 
1. Request queuing and prioritization
2. Effective request cache and memory management
3. Extensibility and customization of the library to our needs
4. Cancelling the requests
here's a good tutorial to start with it : http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/